# Trying to get stock values into a list

Tags: r

I am  trying to create a Neuralnet app in R that gets the last 20 years of 20 stocks using
GetSP500stocks.  That part works just fine, but when I try to get the price adjusted out of that list into a new list to then calculate the 10, 50, and 200 moving day average I get the following error

[image: screenshot of error]

Even tried to use specific column name
df_Svalues[[i]] <- stockValues[[i]]$tickers.adjusted
but get the same error.
Can anyone help me with this?

Here is the code I have so far:

```
#import libraries
library(quantmod)
library(BatchGetSymbols)
library(TTR)
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)
library(neuralnet) # Neural net library

#import the first 20 stocks
df_SP500 <- GetSP500Stocks()

tickers <- head(df_SP500$Tickers,20)
head(tickers) # Debug code
str(tickers)  # Debug code

#set date
my_date <- Sys.Date()
first.date <- my_date %m-% years(20)
last.date <- Sys.Date()
print(my_date)    # debug code
print(last.date)  # debug code
print(first.date) # debug code

#pull data from tickers
stockValues <- list()

for (i in 1:length(tickers)){
  stockValues[[i]] <- getSymbols(tickers[i],auto.assign = FALSE, from = first.date)
}

head(stockValues)
str(stockValues)

#set up list for values
df_Svalues <- list()

colnames(stockValues[[i]])

for (i in 1:length(tickers)){
  df_Svalues[[i]] <- stockValues[[i]]$tickers.adjusted
  df_Svalues[[i]]$mav10 <- 0
  df_Svalues[[i]]$mav50 <- 0
  df_Svalues[[i]]$mav200 <- 0
}
str(df_Svalues)
```

Comment: To improve your reproducible example, could you remove any unnecessary lines (``head``, ``view``, ``str``, ``print`` - i.e. functions that don't have any impact on the final result) - it'll make it easier for others to help you. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```r
#import libraries
library(quantmod)
library(BatchGetSymbols)
library(TTR)
library(shiny)
library(lubridate)
library(neuralnet) # Neural net library

#import the first 20 stocks
df_SP500 <- GetSP500Stocks()

tickers <- head(df_SP500$Tickers,20)

#set date
my_date <- Sys.Date()
first.date <- my_date %m-% years(20)
last.date <- Sys.Date()

#pull data from tickers
stockValues <- list()

for (i in 1:length(tickers)){
  stockValues[[i]] <- getSymbols(tickers[i],auto.assign = FALSE, from = first.date)
}

#set up list for values
df_Svalues <- list()
for (i in 1:length(tickers)){
  df_Svalues[[i]] <- stockValues[[i]][,paste0(tickers[i], ".Adjusted")]
  df_Svalues[[i]]$mav10 <- 0
  df_Svalues[[i]]$mav50 <- 0
  df_Svalues[[i]]$mav200 <- 0
}
head(df_Svalues[[1]])
#>            MMM.Adjusted mav10 mav50 mav200
#> 2002-05-09     37.62977     0     0      0
#> 2002-05-10     37.80853     0     0      0
#> 2002-05-13     38.28524     0     0      0
#> 2002-05-14     38.72916     0     0      0
#> 2002-05-15     38.58317     0     0      0
#> 2002-05-16     38.55637     0     0      0
```

<sup>Created on 2022-05-09 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

The difference is that this line:

```r
  df_Svalues[[i]] <- stockValues[[i]]$tickers.adjusted
```

should be changed to the one below:

```r
  df_Svalues[[i]] <- stockValues[[i]][,paste0(tickers[i], ".Adjusted")]
```

In R if you're trying to make a name out of a variable, you need to paste the variable value and other character string together first.   Or at least that's how I've always done it.  Alternatively, you could have used `stockValues[[i]][,6]` if the values you want are always in the sixth column.

Comment: Hey Dave, That worked perfectly, I am now trying the next bit of code and I am getting this error

Comment: Am I allowed to contact you directly or should I submit another question?  Bill.

Comment: Just post another question and if I can, I'll answer it.